# ora-12505 error with sql developer connecting to oracle11g on windows 7

Tags: oracle11g

I installed oracle 11g successfully and was able to login with SQL plus.
When I tried making a connection with the same username and password via SQL developer however I'm getting the ora-12505 error

[image: error]

Printout of my tnsname.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLE11G =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oracle11g)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

When I execute the tnspint orcl; I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>tnsping ORCL;

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 22-JUL-2013 00:52:10

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Could anyone assist in solving this problem and getting sql developer connected with my oracle database?

Answer (score 3):

Just Run This command in RUN SQL Command 
after connecting to username and password credentials.

command:

```
alter system set local_listener='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))';
```

Answer (score 1):

removed listener.ora file in the directory: [oracle-home]\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN after which it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

- Go to Start > cmd
- Type `lsnrctl status` and check ‘Listener parameter file’ for path of tnsnames.ora
- Go to the location, open file tnsnames.ora & check if SID is present. If not create one.
  [image: sample file tnsnames.ora]

Highlighted name is SID.

- If the service is down go to:
  Start > All Programs > Oracle-*HOME_NAME* > **Configuration and Migration Tools** > **Administration Assistant for Windows**

[image: sample screen print of admin tool]

- Note: Here my SID is ‘ORCL’ then I checked in tnsnames.ora file
- Right click and click ‘stop service’
- Again Right click and click ‘start service’
- For more info:
  [start/stop oracle services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/admin.htm#i1005895)
- If you face problems for starting up please follow steps in:
  [ORA-00600](https://dbatricksworld.com/alter-database-open-failed-with-ora-00600-internal-error-code-arguments-kcratr_nab_less_than_odr-1-160296-591-656/)